# How can Tensorboard files be merged/combined or appended?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, tensorboard

If I have multiple Tensorboard files, how can they be combined into a single Tensorboard file?

Say in keras the following `model.fit()` was called multiple times for a single model, for example in a typical GAN implementation:

```
for i in range(num_epochs):
    model.fit(epochs=1, callbacks=Tensorboard())
```

This will produce a new Tensorboard file each time, which is not useful.  Not sure if there is way to have Tensorboard append, or not produce unique time-stamped files each callback call.

Comment: I don't get what  do you mean by merging the files, But if you put all you TB folder in a global one , and start TB using this global folder you  you can see all those records in Tensorboard !

Answer (score 3):

It seems in tensorboard 2.3, you can access the tensorboard file's logged data and load it into a pandas dataframe. This tutorial outlines the approach:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/dataframe_api

At the time of writing, I couldn't find a tensorboard version 2.3, but the module the tutorial relies upon - tensorboard.data.experimental.ExperimentFromDev() - seems to be present in tensorboard 2.2: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/tensorboard/data/experimental/experiment_from_dev.py#L71

You could load existing data from several tensorboard files into dataframes and then combine those dataframes in the desired manner to write the combined dataframe to a new tensorboard file. I had considered this approach to address the problem of having multiple tensorboard files for different training runs but haven't tried it yet in my project.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon this question, you can use **initial_epoch** defined in [model.fit()](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit)

Inside the for loop, initial_epoch can be changed every time model.fit() is called.

Answer (score 0):

New link for the `initial_epoch` documentation: https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/

Also note that epochs will also need to be changed.

```
for i in range(num_epochs):
    model.fit(epochs=i, initial_epoch=i-1, callbacks=Tensorboard())
```

because

> Note that in conjunction with initial_epoch, epochs is to be understood as "final epoch". The model is not trained for a number of iterations given by epochs, but merely until the epoch of index epochs is reached.